# Pass <cword> and environment var to vim function

Tags: vim

I have a vim function Ag that I would like to call with some parameters one of them the current word (`<cword>`) and an environment var

Currently I've got this:

```
nnoremap <C-\> :Ag <cword> <C-r>=$projects<CR>
```

evals `$projects` but not `<cword>`

```
nnoremap <C-\> :Ag <cword> $projects<CR>
```

evals `<cword>` but not $projects

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `expand('<cword>')` with `execute` to expand the word under the cursor.

```
nnoremap <C-\> :exec 'Ag' expand('<cword>') '$projects'<CR>
```

Take a look at `:h expand()` and `:h execute`

Comment: Thanks you! been killing me all day.